# Magento Custom Register Page - Redirect Issue

Tags: customer, controllers, register

I created a custom register-trade.phtml for trade customer signups that I am pulling into a CMS page.

The issue is if a customer enters something wrong e.g. their email is already in use it redirects to /customer/account/create/ and shows the normal register form.

This form is different, has different fields and ultimately will not sign the user up in the trade group.

Can I redirect to the trade register page and display the error rather than going to /customer/account/create/ ?

Comment: Where is the `register-trade.phtml` file posting data to, does it have it's own set of controllers, or does it post to the same place as the standard register, but with different fields in the form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Copy that file to the local code pool and amend the `_loginPostRedirect()` function.

Change this line to do something else:

```
$session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
```

Basically that line sets the redirect to the standard login page if the customer login does not work. You can change that to go back to the previous page, e.g.:

```
 $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true))
```

Whether that will work given the many login routes you have I do not know, however, this should get you on the right track for what you are trying to achieve. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! All i have done is literally coped register.phtml and made register-trade.phtml in template. If I copy AccountController.php into local and edit it how will I make only the register-trade.phtml redirect to the previous page?